# Catch key pressed on Form1 from the Class

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling, keypress

Here is my class with event handler:

```
public delegate void MyKeyEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e);

public class KeyEvent
{
    public event MyKeyEventHandler keyEvent;
    public string key = "";

    protected virtual void KeyPressed(KeyEventArgs e) 
    {
        MyKeyEventHandler handler = keyEvent;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    public KeyEvent()
    {
        keyEvent += new MyKeyEventHandler(keyPressed);
    }

    private void keyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        key = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    }
}
```

And in my Form1 I have this code: (EDITED)

```
KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ke.key);
}
```

When I run form and press key on keyboard and then click on button it pop up empty MessageBox. What I want is everytime I press a key on keyboard a MessageBox to pop up and show me which key I pressed. This code is just for testing, I don't want just to pop up message box, I need the key for other things.

Note: To handle the events on Form1 is not a solution, I need to handle the events in class. I making a libray.

Comment: Where is that code on Form1?  In what method of the form is that being called?  It's just a new instance of the event class, so of course it's empty.  Where are you tying it to an actual "key pressed" event at the form level?

Comment: Pff I put it on Form1_Load but where I must write this code?

Comment: I just want to test if the event catch the key pressed before continue

Comment: You're going to have to wire it to the form in some way, because that's where the key press is occurring.  Once you have it, then do what you wish via the class.  What is your goal?

Comment: Trying to handle a *heavily* UI related event like a key press in a library is just not the correct way.  Look at the ProcessCmdKey() method and the IMessageFilter interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.KeyPreview = true;
            f.KeyDown += f_KeyDown;
            Application.Run(f);
        }

        static void f_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.KeyValue.ToString());
        }
    }
```

If you enable KeyPreview you will receive all keyDowns even of the controls placed on the Form. If you set it to false you only get the KeyDown when the Form has focus.

As you can see in the code you can connect any KeyDownEventHandler method in any class to the Form.

As there where questions left:

```
 public class FormKeyListener
    {
        private Form formToListen = null;
        public void SetFormToListen(Form form)
        {

            if (formToListen != null)
                formToListen.KeyDown -= formToListen_KeyDown; // Unregister from old form if present

            formToListen = form;
            formToListen.KeyDown += formToListen_KeyDown; // Attach to new form
        }

        void formToListen_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.KeyValue.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Which can be call this way somewhere in your code:

```
FormKeyListener fkl = new FormKeyListener();
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.KeyPreview = true;
fkl.SetFormToListen(f);
```

Comment: I making a library so modifying the program.cs is not a solution... I should wrote it, sorry :S

Comment: @Loclip You can put the code wherever you want; all you need is an instance of a form that you can manipulate these members of.

Comment: As you can see Program is just like any class. So you can put this code into any other (also non static) class.

Comment: Added slightly other solution that does not involve Program.cs.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible for you to create a class that is capable of just automatically listening for events generated by its parent.  How would that work?  What would happen if you created a new `KeyEvent` class using something that wasn't a `Form` and didn't raise events?

You are going to need to give your `KeyEvent` class a reference to whatever thing that you want to monitor key events for.  I realize that your intention is to create some third-party library, so you'd like to keep things as generic as possible in order to maximize its reuse.  Since you are dependent on the `KeyDown` event, using `Control` is the most generic you can be.  This is because it is where the `KeyDown` event is actually defined.

Let me show you what I mean...

**1) Modify the constructor of your `KeyEvent` class to accept an instance of `Control`**

```
public class KeyEvent
{
    // You don't need to declare an internal event
    public string key = "";
    private Control _control;

    public KeyEvent(Control control)
    {
        // Here is where we save the reference of Control that was passed to the class.
        // This will enable you to access the instance of the Form or whatever else
        // you want to use, which is helpful for unregistering events during cleanup
        _control = control;

        // Wire up your event handler to this SPECIFIC instance of Control.
        // This will cause your `keyPressed` method to execute whenever
        // the control raises the KeyDown event.  All of the middleman
        // event handling you are doing is unnecessary.
        _control.KeyDown += keyPressed;
    }

    private void keyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        key = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    }

}
```

**2) Modify the parent in which you are creating this `KeyEvent` to pass itself into the `KeyEvent`**

```
// Now you pass 'this' into the constructor.  This can be a Form, or any other
// Winforms control that may inherit from Control (which is all of them)
KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(this);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // At this point, ke.Key will always display the last
    // key pressed in the Form when the button is clicked.
    MessageBox.Show(ke.key);
}
```

Comment: Note that he most likely doesn't want to subscribe to the `KeyDown` event of the form; he wants to subscribe to the `PreviewKeyDown` event so that it will fire even if a child control has focus.

Comment: Either way it's the exact same idea.  He could even subscribe to multiple key events and handle them each in different ways.  There was no specific key event mentioned in the question, so I just picked one.

Comment: The `PreviewKeyDown` isn't in `Control`, it's specific to `Form`, so he'd need to accept a `Form` instance.

Comment: @MikeC when I put `KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(this);` form load it give me again empty message box, when i put it in the Form1_KeyDown its give me exception error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Fair enough. However, without knowing the OPs exact requirements we're really just speculating.  I'll tweak the example if it turns out he actually needs that specific event, in the meantime I'll lean towards the more generic solution.

Comment: @Loclip Also, you don't put `KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(this)` into `Form_Load`, otherwise that reference will go out of scope.  If you put it exactly where I did in my example, that declares `ke` as a protected member variable, which will make it live for the entire life of the `Form`